# How to prevent registration to Firebase project?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

As per the Firebase documentation, the contents of google-services.json are considered public. These can be easily retrieved by decompiling the apk.
If so, is there a way to prevent apps from registering with my Firebase project?

I understand that the registration works on the basis of package name. While it's not possible to publish an app with a duplicate package name, for development it is very much possible.

I created a dummy app, and my dummy app successfully registered with my production project. So, looking for a way to prevent that from happening.

Answer (score 0):

You should be connecting your app to Firebase Emulator for local development.

You can go to Firebase console -> Authentication tab -> Sign-in Method tab, and remove localhost from Authorized domain, that way your app will never connect to production DB.

Comment: I'm trying to assess the security of my app. So, I do not want any impostor app to be able to register with my firebase project.
I do not have a DB. I am using FCM. So, I want to prevent unauthentic apps from connecting to my project.